# Test and evaluate flyway 6.1.4

Tags: flyway

I want to test and evaluate flyway 6.1.4.
When will the version be available in JCenter?
I am able to download it, but I am not allowed to upload it to our artifactory instance.

Comment: Can you not use Maven Central instead of JCenter?

Comment: No sorry I'm just a consumer and my colleague don't support it.

Comment: No problem - check out https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2646 and if there's any more context you can give us that would be very helpful.

Comment: Think that's the reason why. We changed from nexus to artifactory one month ago and therefore from Sonatype to jfrog.